# :Invalid argument during shmat on AIX 5.3

Tags: c, unix, ipc, shared-memory, aix

Below is the code i am trying to use , built successfully,
while executing i got the below error: 
unable to attach shmem to current process
: Invalid argument

i tried same program with another key 5678, still the same error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>


int main(int argc,char * argv[],char * envp[])
{

        key_t key = ftok("/usr/tmp");
        int shmflag = IPC_CREAT|0666;
        int shmid;
        char * shm,*s;

        if((shmid = shmget(key,27,shmflag)<0))
        {
                perror("unable to get shmem\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        //attaching a shmem.
        if((shm = shmat(shmid,NULL,0)) == (char *)-1)
        {
                perror("unable to attach shmem to current process\n");
                exit(-2);
        }

        s = shm;
        strcpy(s,"Hi Pavan here");
        *s = NULL;

        while(*shm != '*')
                sleep(1);

        if((shmdt(shm))<0)
        {
                perror("unable to detach\n");
                exit(-3);
        }
        exit(0);
}
```

results of ipcs -a reflecting the shared memories i created :

]ipcs -a|grep -i tstbld

q 554696745 0x34000002 --rw-rw-rw-   tstbld    staff   tstbld    staff         0         0   4194304 1638630 1638632  6:11:30  6:11:37  6:01:58

q 632291424 0x2c000002 --rw-rw-rw-   tstbld    staff   tstbld    staff         0         0   4194304      0      0 no-entry no-entry  6:11:13

m 659554320 0x2c000060 --rw-rw-rw-   tstbld    staff   tstbld    staff      0        27 733346     0 no-entry no-entry  9:54:16

m 887095320 0x0000162e --rw-rw-rw-   tstbld    staff   tstbld    staff      0        27 1568944     0 no-entry no-entry  9:15:46

could any of you please let me know what  i am missing here.
if i have to attach the shared memory at particular virtual address, how i will know which is the proper available address that i can use to attach the Shmem region.

Minimum SHMEM limit on AIX 5.3 is 1 byte and Max is some TB.

Comment: As a start, add the missing includes: string.h, stdlib.h
Also fix `ftok`: it takes two parameters

Comment: i am not getting any compilation or linker issues.BTW  i used ftok in the same way for message queues key an  it worked fine.